# What's the image of $f(z)=\tan^2(z)$ in region $D$ given as:

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

Find the image of $f(z)=\tan^2(z)$, $D=\{z: 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<\pi/2\}$. I don't know if what I did was correct. I have no way to confirm it. I got that the result is $w=f(z)$, so $\operatorname{Im}(w)=0$, $-1 \leq \operatorname{Re}(w) \leq 0$.

First I used the fact that $\tan^2(z)=(\sin(z)/\cos(z))^2$ and I opened up the brackets, where
$\sin(z)=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/2i$, and $\cos(z)=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$.

I graphed the complex plane, and saw the region that was given, I called a few segments, let's say the segment where $(y=0, x:0 \to \pi/2)$, I called this segment I,
then segment II is $(x=\pi/2, y=0 \to \infty)$, and so on, I got a few segments, I wanted to see how
$\tan^2(z)$ copies each segment, then kind of puzzle in the mappings and see what the total mapping is.

What I got is that the mapping is literally the interval $[-1,0]$. But I am not sure, and I have no way to confirm..

Comment: Shouldn't you at least get that $(0, \infty)$ is a subset of the image since the image of $\left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ under $\tan$ is $(0, \infty)$? (But the true image is strictly bigger.) You can also see that $0$ should not be in the image since $\sin z$ is never zero in your region. Moreover, $-1$ should not also be in the image since $\tan z$ never takes the value $\pm \iota$.